# Running Cucumber feature files on VS code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I have a cloned project on web automation with cucumber in java, I have opened it in VS Code and I want to run the .feature files but I do not seem to get the way around it. I wanted to try the same on eclipse but opening the files on eclipse gives so many errors that are not seen on VS Code. Is it possible that I run the feature files on vs code?

I tried using the test on the left panel but it didn't work.

Comment: _Is it possible that I run the feature files on vs code?_ Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Vscode requires different extensions to implement functions in different languages. The following two extensions may help you. You can also search for more extensions that may be useful to you in the [extension panel](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace).

**[Cucumber (Gherkin) Full Support](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alexkrechik.cucumberautocomplete)**

**[Cucumber Quick](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AbhinabaGhosh.cucumberquick)**

> - If Run Feature is selected, the complete feature file will be executed

Comment: I have both extensions but they did not help. I guess in the mean time I will use IntelliJ because  it did help and is easy to use.